# When to upgrade an AWS instance - how much RAM should an app use?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, system-administration

I'm no sys-admin, but I use Amazon to host a number of applications. I'm getting some strange readings from one of my EC2 instances, which coincide with poor performance and the site being offline. I understand the AWS EC2 will cut server performance down to safe levels if it exceeds its resources, which seems to be what is happening. SO my questions for any AWS experts out there... (see attached screenshot)

1. how much RAM should a php database-driven website be using (the site has about 100 users a day at this stage)? 1gb (T2.Micro instance + EBS) doesn't seem to cut it!
2. Does this look like a memory-leak in some of our scripts?
3. Does this look like malicious activity on the server?
4. Is this caused by resource-heavy DB calls? (tens of thousands of records, but not a vast number of users, >100 users)

[image: AWS top screenshot]

**I have tried :** 
Relaunching the instance (a number of times) provides a temporary fix.
Upgrading from nano to micro instance (fixed it for about a week until we began to run into trouble again) 
Thanks!

**EDIT:** 
This is after being up for 4.5 hours 
[image]

**EDIT:** 
This is after being up for 19 hours 
[image]

**EDIT:** 
Running strace on cfn-hup results in thousands of entries like this: 
[image: strace cfn-hup]

Comment: This system has not been up long enough for the numbers to be realistic. Post another screenshot after (at least) 24 hours of normal activity. Also monitor your CPU credits during this timeframe and post a screenshot.

Comment: What is the tech stack you are using?

Comment: @Auriga Apache > php 7.1 > Laravel . “Eloquent” DB calls to MySQL on RDS instance

Comment: @JohnHanley please see edits - added screenshots of processes. Not sure how to monitor CPU credits...?

Comment: You have T2 instance. Make sure you didn't hit CPU burst limit (via AWS console=> instance=>metrics)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it can be many things. Try recreating the instance and migrating to the new instance.

If the CPU activity is still super high then memory leak, or resource-heavy DB call.

If that fixes, then it sounded like it might have been a virus.

Comment: I have migrated instance to a new instance. Fixed temporarily but the problem crept back after a week or so.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things I can think of.

Try to enable slow query log in MySQL, and address the slow queries if found.

Try `sudo strace -p <httpd_Main_Process_ID> -o httpd_trace.txt`, then analyze the file  and see if there's something suspicious in the WebApp - This will give you everything `httpd` process is doing.

Comment: See result of strace on cfn-hup process. Is that normal? Why so many blank selects?

Comment: Thanks, I don't see anything odd. These selects are kernel calls, has nothing to do with the webapp. Can you try strace with httpd process, not cfn-hub?